# How to eliminate zeros in simulated data from rnorm function

Tags: r, statistics, data-science, transformation

I have a large set of high frequency data of wind. I use this data in a model to calculate gas exchange between atmosphere and water. I am using the average wind of a 10-day series of measurements to represent gas exchange at a given time. Since the wind is an average value from a 10-day series I want to apply the error to the output by adding the error to the input:

```r
#fictional time series, manually created by me.
wind <- c(0,0,0,0,0,4,3,2,4,3,2,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,4,5,4,3,2,1,0,0,0,0,0)
```

I then create 100 values around the mean and sd of the wind vector:

```
df <- as.data.frame(mapply(rnorm,mean=mean(wind),sd=sd(wind),n=100))
```

The standard deviation generates negative values. If these are run in the gas exchange model I get disproportionately large error simply because wind speed can't be negative and the model is not constructed to be capable to run with negative wind measurements. I have been suggested to log transform the raw data and run the `rnorm()` with logged values, and then transform back. But since there are several zeros in the data (0=no wind) I can't simply log the values. Hence I use the `log(x+c)` method:

```
wind.log <- log(wind+1)  
df.log <-  as.data.frame(mapply(rnorm,
            mean=mean(wind.log),
            sd=sd(wind.log),n=100))
```

However, I will need to convert values back to actual wind measurements before running them in the model.
This is where it gets problematic, since I will need to use `exp(x)-c` to convert values back and then I end up with negative values again.

Is there a way to work around this without truncating the 0's and screwing up the generated distribution around the mean?

My only alternative is otherwise is to calculate gas exchange directly at every given time point and generate a distribution from that, those values would never be negative or = 0 and can hence be log-transformed.

Comment: This seems like more of a stats question than a programming question to me.  Maybe move to https://stats.stackexchange.com/?  If the example data is representative (lots of 0 values plus positive values, likely right skewed), you could try working with a Tweedie distribution where 1 < p < 2 (a compound Poisson-gamma distribution).  That seems like it could well represent your data.  Otherwise maybe a truncated normal?

Comment: Ye the example I generated manually to make sure negative values where generated using rnorm, the wind data is looking sort of like that but the vector is much longer and a wee bit more complex.

Thanks alot for your suggestions, is going to worth looking into and read about. I did not know about the stats forum. Anyhow, I am very pleased with the answer I've got here =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestion: use a zero-inflated/altered model, where you generate some proportion of zero values and draw the rest from a log-normal distribution(to make sure you don't get negative values):

```r
wind <- c(0,0,0,0,0,4,3,2,4,3,2,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,4,5,4,3,2,1,0,0,0,0,0)
prop_nonzero <- mean(wind>0)
lmean <- mean(log(wind[wind>0]))
lsd <- sd(log(wind[wind>0]))
n <- 500
vals <- rbinom(n, size=1,prob=prop_nonzero)*rlnorm(n,meanlog=lmean,sdlog=lsd)
```

Alternatively you could use a Tweedie distribution (as suggested by @aosmith), or fit a *censored* model to estimate the distribution of wind values that get measured as zero (assuming that the wind speed is never *exactly* zero, just too small to measure)

Comment: Thank you. This answer was very useful and straight on point.
It still creates a right skewed distribution but it generates the same mean as in the original vector which is great, cheers!